# Proof by contrapositive and vector set

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A=$\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,...,\mathbf{v}_n\}$ and
> B=$\{\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2,...,\mathbf{u}_l\}$ be two **disjoint**
> subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$. If there exists a vector **w≠0** which
> belongs to the linear span both of A and B, then A∪B is linearly dependent.

My attempt was to prove this statement using a contrapositive condition and сounterexample.

Let A=$\{(0,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$ and B=$\{(0,0,1)\}$.

The contrapositive condition is: If A∪B is linearly independent → **w**∉Span(A) ∨ **w**∉Span(B).

But the vector **w**=(1,1,1) is **w**∈Span(A∪B). Thus, the original statement is correct and A∪B is linearly dependent.

I'm not sure if my proof is correct, because it sounds too easy to prove this way and maybe I miss something around the condition of **w**∈Span(A∪B).

Comment: Your proof is not correct.  You have to prove something is **always** true.  You cannot do that by giving one example.  Writing it in terms of the contrapositive does not change this.

Comment: There is probably some incorrect wording going on here... you say $A$ and $B$ are **distinct** subsets.  Do you maybe mean that $A$ and $B$ are **disjoint** instead?  As it is currently worded, $A=\{(1,0)\}, B=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ are technically distinct since $A\neq B$, and we have $(1,0)$ is in the span of both $A$ and $B$, but $A\cup B = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is still a linearly independent set.  Recall that $\cup$ is not the same thing as $\sqcup$ and duplicates which exist in both sets in the union will exist only once in the result.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for my English

Comment: Now... if $A$ and $B$ are **disjoint**, then for a direct proof we have since $w$ is in the span of $A$ there exist constants $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ with some nonzero such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n = w$ as well as constants $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_l$ such that $d_1u_1+d_2u_2+\dots+d_lu_l = w$.  Then we have $c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n-d_1u_1-\dots-d_lu_l = w-w=0$ which gives an example of constants with some nonzero that can be applied to $v_1,\dots,v_n,u_1,\dots,u_l$ such that they combine to become zero, which is the very definition of what it means to be linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove says $\mathbf w \notin \text{span}(A)$ or $\mathbf w \notin \text{span}(B)$. I.e., that $\text{span}(A) \cap \text{span}(B) = \emptyset$. But what you have shown is that $\mathbf w \in \text{span}(A \cup B)$. That is something entirely different. In fact, your $\mathbf w$ is not in either  $\text{span}(A)$ or $\text{span}(B)$.